# Get the probability generating function of $X$ from $Y$

Tags: probability, generating-functions

For $X\in $Bin($n,p$) and $Y|X=k \in$Bin($k,p$), I have to show using the pgf that $Y \in$Bin($n,p^2$). I have been shown that the pgf of $Y$ can be written as,
$$
g_Y(t)=E[t^Y]=E[E[t^Y|X]]=\sum_{k=0}^{n} E[t^Y|X=k]P(X=k)
$$
What I don't understand is why (when using the conditional) is it $P(X=k)$ and not $P(Y=k)$?

Edit: Also, what happened with $t^k$, i.e. why is it not $(E[t^Y|X=k])^k$?

Comment: Cause in $E[E[t^Y|X]]$ you are conditioning respect to $X$

Comment: Yes, that I know, but since the formula is $g_Y(t)=\sum t^k f_Y(y)$, how has it been used above?

Comment: No. You are confusing the probability generating  function with the steps done (which isn't wrong, but it is not necesarily). You have $E[t^Y]$, that's right?. Then, by properties of conditional expectation, $E[t^Y]=E[E[t^Y|X]]$ (review the properties of conditional expectation). And, by "defitnion", the last is $\sum_{k=0}^n E[... \mbox{bla bla bla}$.

Comment: Ahhh, I totally missed that, I will check it right now. Thanks @sinbadh!